# How to perform custom sort

Tags: sort

I have the following line in a file :

```
[[0, [0, '1']], [1, [0, '2']], [2, [0, '3']], [3, [0, '4']]]
[[0, [1, '5']], [1, [1, '6']], [2, [1, '7']], [3, [1, '8']]]
[[0, [2, '9']], [1, [2, '10']], [2, [2, '11']], [3, [2, '12']]]
```

Is there a way to sort them on the first character (0,1,2 or 3) in the inner list element so that I will end up with the following:

```
[[0, [0, '1']], [0, [1, '5']],[0, [2, '9']]]
[[1, [0, '2']], [1, [1, '6']],[1, [2, '10']]]
```

and so on?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a programming language that can parse that structure.

Comment: You don't want to sort them, you want to change their structure. You are creating new arrays that contain the elements of the old ones but completely changing the original arrays, that is not sorting. Since this is not a human readable format, I assume it is part of a larger project, are you using any particular programming language for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not particularly elegant but it will do what you need. At least, it does on the example you posted:

```
perl -ne 'while(s/(\[(\d),\s*\[.+?\]\])//){push @{$k{$2}},$1 . ",";} 
          END{ print "[@{$k{$_}}]\n" for keys(%k)}' file.txt | 
sed 's/,\]$/\]/' | sort
```

Running the command above on a file called `file.txt` that contains the lines from your example gives the following output:

```
[[0, [0, '1']], [0, [1, '5']], [0, [2, '9']]]
[[1, [0, '2']], [1, [1, '6']], [1, [2, '10']]]
[[2, [0, '3']], [2, [1, '7']], [2, [2, '11']]]
[[3, [0, '4']], [3, [1, '8']], [3, [2, '12']]]
```

---

#### Explanation

I will not explain in detail since this is actually a small program and uses quite a few features of Perl. The basic idea of the Perl script is to find all cases of `[\d, [.+?]]` where `\d` is any number and `.+?]]` is everything up to the *first* `]]`. This will basically collect all the different sub-arrays or tuples or whatever these are and save them in a hash of arrays whose key is the first digit, the one you want to sort on. Once the whole file has been processed, it will print each array of the hash. This is the output of the script alone:

```
$ perl -ne 'while(s/(\[(\d),\s*\[.+?\]\])//){push @{$k{$2}},$1 . ",";} 
          END{ print "[@{$k{$_}}]\n" for keys(%k)}' file.txt 
[[1, [0, '2']], [1, [1, '6']], [1, [2, '10']],]
[[3, [0, '4']], [3, [1, '8']], [3, [2, '12']],]
[[0, [0, '1']], [0, [1, '5']], [0, [2, '9']],]
[[2, [0, '3']], [2, [1, '7']], [2, [2, '11']],]
```

I am separating each sub array with a `,` but that means I get an extra one at the end so I use `sed` to remove that.

```
$ perl -ne 'while(s/(\[(\d),\s*\[.+?\]\])//){push @{$k{$2}},$1 . ",";} 
>           END{ print "[@{$k{$_}}]\n" for keys(%k)}' file.txt | 
> sed 's/,\]$/\]/' 
[[1, [0, '2']], [1, [1, '6']], [1, [2, '10']]]
[[3, [0, '4']], [3, [1, '8']], [3, [2, '12']]]
[[0, [0, '1']], [0, [1, '5']], [0, [2, '9']]]
[[2, [0, '3']], [2, [1, '7']], [2, [2, '11']]]
```

Finally, you also wanted this sorted but since they now are organized by their first character, a simple `sort` will do:

```
$ perl -ne 'while(s/(\[(\d),\s*\[.+?\]\])//){push @{$k{$2}},$1 . ",";} 
          END{ print "[@{$k{$_}}]\n" for keys(%k)}' file.txt | 
sed 's/,\]$/\]/' | sort
[[0, [0, '1']], [0, [1, '5']], [0, [2, '9']]]
[[1, [0, '2']], [1, [1, '6']], [1, [2, '10']]]
[[2, [0, '3']], [2, [1, '7']], [2, [2, '11']]]
[[3, [0, '4']], [3, [1, '8']], [3, [2, '12']]]
```

Comment: My eyes hurt 8-)

Comment: @slm try taking your glasses off, it looks better when not in focus :)